# Rails image_tag not closing image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, html-helper, xhtml

On a rails project I am using the image_tag to generate my image html elements.

```
<%= image_tag("test.jpg", :alt => "test image") %>
```

is generating

```
<img src="test.jpg" alt="test image">
```

This is happening throughout my entire rails project.

Is there a setting somewhere that someone else set that is causing this?
How can I get rails to always close the image tag?

Comment: I have searched Google for a while and still can't find an answer.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using. My Rails 2.3.2, MacOS closes it.

Comment: Technically, `img` tags in HTML don't need closing. They are only required in XHTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

image_tag is implemented in terms of [ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper.tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html) which takes an optional third parameter that says whether to close the tag or not (for XHTML compliance).  By default it's off, but something is setting yours to true.  Not sure where.  You should be able to say

```
 tag(:img, { :src => "test.jpg" }, false)
```

to force it.

---

Notice the use of `:img` instead of `"img"`. `:img` is a [symbol](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2005/08/19/understanding-ruby-symbols), that is basically a string that gets only created once. A new string `"img"` on the other hand would get created every time you would call `tag`, therefore consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: Rails 3 is using a lot of the new HTML5 standard, and in HTML5 the non-closing <img> is valid.